# 'ORA-00911: invalid character' when SQL statement has semi-colon in the middle of the string

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, groovy-sql

Has anyone encountered `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character` when making `sql.execute('...')` ([1](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29)) call with SQL statement that has ';' (semi-colon) characters in the middle of it. I'm aware that trailing semi-colon causes ORA-00911 as suggested here [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855799/understanding-mysterious-oracle-jdbc-errors-ora-00911-invalid-character) so am already stripping them out)

Here's an example of one such SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO metadata_property_qualifier(id,version,metadata_property_id,name,overridable,propagated,to_instance,to_subclass,translatable,type,value,value_type)
    VALUES (mpr_qualifier_sequence.nextval,0,(select id from metadata_property where metadata_class_id
    IN (select id from metadata_class where name = 'UIM_DXTPMLanSwitchError')
    AND metadata_property.name='CollisNumberValidity'),'ValueMap',0,0,0,0,0,'[Ljava.lang.String;',unistr('0\00a31'),19)
```

Note that  `[Ljava.lang.String;` has `;` character in it.
Is there a way to escape semi-colon or workaround it somehow?

Code snippet:

```
sqlFile.eachLine() {
    log.info it
    if(!it.startsWith('--') && !it.trim().isEmpty()) {
        try {                       
            sql.execute(it - ';')
        } catch(ex) {
            log.error ex
            log.info "Rolling back the transaction..."
            sql.dataSource.connection.rollback()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Offhand, it seems as though this should be OK. Can you include your entire code snippet?

Comment: Mureinik, I updated the description. Thank you for checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-` ([minus](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#minus%28java.lang.Object%29)) only replaces the first occurrence.  If you have multiple semicolons in your SQL, you'll want to use `replaceAll()`.