# "WITH" SQL query not working java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am using "with data as" as in below query. When I run this in sql developer, it's executing fine, but in java code when I call the query as normal string or through jdbc template in xml configuration file, it gives me bad SQL grammar. Is there any alternative to the below query?

```
public class NppGWOrphanMessageDao extends DefaultDao {
String sql = "same sql as i posted"
private String replayGWOrphanMsgSQL;

public void setReplayGWOrphanMsgSQL(String replayGWOrphanMsgSQL) {
    this.replayGWOrphanMsgSQL = replayGWOrphanMsgSQL;
}

public String getReplayGWOrphanMsgSQL() { return replayGWOrphanMsgSQL; }

public List<Map<String, Object>> getReplayList(HashMap<String, Object> epoch) { 
    return retrieveAll(replayGWOrphanListSQL, params); 
    return retrieveAll(sql, epoch); }
}
```

```sql
WITH DATA AS ( 
    SELECT GLOB.ID, GLOB.CHARACTERS 
    FROM GW_LOB_STORE GLOB 
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM GW_NPP_MSG_INTEGRITY M WHERE M.LOB_STORE_ID=GLOB.ID) 
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM GW_NPP_SAFE_STORE S WHERE S.LOB_STORE_ID=GLOB.ID)
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM GW_POISON_LOG P WHERE P.LOB_STORE_ID=GLOB.ID)
        AND GLOB.CREATED_TS > = :epoch)
SELECT 
    A.ID AS "GLOBID", 
    INQUEUEDTL.ID AS "INQUEID", 
    A.CHARACTERS AS "REQUESTBODY", 
    INQUEUEDTL.ENDPOINT_ID AS "ENDPOINTID", 
    INQUEUEDTL.HEADER AS "HEADERS" 
FROM DATA A, GW_IN_QUEUE_DETAIL INQUEUEDTL 
WHERE A.ID=INQUEUEDTL.ID;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it gives me ORA - 00911 invalid character \n

Comment: I think  :epoch should be replaced with ?

Comment: no epoc i am replacing with timestamp in the code, it gives me same error even if i hard code epoc with proper value.

Comment: So show your code and real sql

Comment: public class NppGWOrphanMessageDao extends DefaultDao {

    String sql = "same sql as i posted"

    private String replayGWOrphanMsgSQL;

    public void setReplayGWOrphanMsgSQL(String replayGWOrphanMsgSQL) {
        this.replayGWOrphanMsgSQL = replayGWOrphanMsgSQL;
    }

    public String getReplayGWOrphanMsgSQL() {
        return replayGWOrphanMsgSQL;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getReplayList(HashMap<String, Object> epoch) {
        //return retrieveAll(replayGWOrphanListSQL, params);
        return retrieveAll(sql, epoch);
    }

Comment: Please edit your question with **real** code  The fact that the error was to do with sql formatting, then this makes it even more important

Comment: does epoch variable is replace with 'epochValue' (with quote signs)?

Comment: @user3436400 Are you doing the formatting with the double quotes you have with the alias names such as "GLOBID",  "INQUEID" etc. ?

Comment: yes its replacing with quote signs

Comment: @user75ponic yes, i have done the formatting, its posted here as double quotes in real its proper sql query which workes fine in sql developer

Comment: `String sql = "same sql as i posted"`  - this is really what I want to see.  If there is formatting problems here, then *ORA - 00911 invalid character \n* may appear

Comment: @user3436400 Before the line with the `ORA - 00911 invalid character`, try printing the output of `sql` variable and copy the output and execute in SQLDeveloper.

Comment: query, WITH DATA AS
(
SELECT GLOB.ID,
GLOB.CHARACTERS
FROM GW_LOB_STORE GLOB
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM GW_NPP_MSG_INTEGRITY M WHERE M.LOB_STORE_ID=GLOB.ID)
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM GW_NPP_SAFE_STORE S WHERE S.LOB_STORE_ID=GLOB.ID)
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM GW_POISON_LOG P WHERE P.LOB_STORE_ID=GLOB.ID)
AND GLOB.CREATED_TS > = '1501477329')
SELECT A.ID AS "GLOBID", INQUEUEDTL.ID AS "INQUEID", 
A.CHARACTERS AS "REQUESTBODY", 
INQUEUEDTL.ENDPOINT_ID AS "ENDPOINTID",
INQUEUEDTL.HEADER AS "HEADERS"
FROM DATA A,
GW_IN_QUEUE_DETAIL INQUEUEDTL
WHERE A.ID=INQUEUEDTL.ID;

Comment: Do you send the sql code with the semi-colon (the ;) at the end?

Comment: There is a space between `>` and `=`.  It should be `>=`.

Comment: @zuckermanori, yes, we send through semi-colon at the end for al lthe queries

Comment: @saka 1029 i removed space, still no luck.

Comment: @user3436400 Can you try removing the double quotes from the column aliases and execute the Java code?

Comment: Remove `;`.  See [Understanding mysterious Oracle JDBC errors - ORA-00911: invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855799/understanding-mysterious-oracle-jdbc-errors-ora-00911-invalid-character).

Comment: @saka1029 is correct, this is what I was referring to

Comment: Thanks @Zuckermanori this worked

Comment: @saka thanks that worked.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness:

The problem with this query is the `;` at the end of it.

Oracle JDBC driver does not handle it well.